# Getting pandas error while getting dataframe using dask

Tags: python, dask-dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Load a large data file into a Pandas data frame
#pandas_df = pd.read_csv('large_data.csv')
df = pd.read_excel('FinalLeads1502.csv')
# Load the same data file into a Dask data frame
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df)
```

Result:

```
Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-077f1422e5e2> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import dask.dataframe as dd
      3 
      4 # Load a large data file into a Pandas data frame
      5 #pandas_df = pd.read_csv('large_data.csv')
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\__init__.py in <module>
      1 try:
      2     from ..base import compute
----> 3     from . import backends, rolling
      4     from .core import (
      5         DataFrame,
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\backends.py in <module>
----> 1 from .core import get_parallel_type, make_meta, meta_nonempty
      2 from .methods import concat_dispatch
      3 from .utils import group_split_dispatch, hash_object_dispatch
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in <module>
     53     typename,
     54 )
---> 55 from . import methods
     56 from .accessor import DatetimeAccessor, StringAccessor
     57 from .categorical import CategoricalAccessor, categorize
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\methods.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from ..utils import Dispatch
----> 9 from .utils import (
     10     group_split_dispatch,
     11     hash_object_dispatch,
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\utils.py in <module>
    367 
    368 
--> 369 _numeric_index_types = (pd.Int64Index, pd.Float64Index, pd.UInt64Index)
    370 
    371 meta_nonempty = Dispatch("meta_nonempty")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Index'
Read the dataframe correctly
```

Comment: Hi, I would guess this is an environment problem and you Dask version is not up to date, could you check the versions of Pandas and Dask you are using?

Comment: why are you using `read_excel()` to read a csv file? you should be using `read_csv()`